# Conditional Loop, Values not adding to array

Tags: loops, excel, if-statement, vba

I am trying to read in a single value for WC(1). I would then like to use the initial value of WC(j) in a conditional loop. I get the first value of WC(j) to run smoothly (it meets the first condition in the loop), however, the first condition is supposed to establish the next value in the WC(j) array. However, it doesnt establish a value to the array it just says empty. Specifically in these lines:
WC(j) = fc
WCinit(j) = WC(j - 1)

When I step through the code, it will say fc=0.3 but WC(j) is empty even though I have set them equal to eachother. Since the WC(j) value is empty, it will only meet the 'else' condition of my loop.

It has the same problem with the next line of code, there is a value for WC(j-1) and it is set equal to WCinit(j), but WCinit(j) stays empty.

```
  Dim Month() As Double
  Dim WC() As Variant
  Dim WCinit() As Variant
  Dim NumMonth As Long, i As Long, j As Long

  Dim Precip() As Double
  Dim RefET() As Double
  Dim Runoff() As Double
  Dim Percolation() As Double

  Sub main()
    WaterBalanceReadMediterranean
    WaterBalanceMediterranean
    WaterBalanceReadPlains
    WaterBalancePlains
End Sub
Sub WaterBalanceReadMediterranean()
    NumMonth = 12

    ReDim Month(1 To NumMonth)
    ReDim WCinit(1 To NumMonth + 1)
    ReDim WC(1 To NumMonth + 1)
    ReDim Precip(1 To NumMonth)
    ReDim RefET(1 To NumMonth)
    ReDim Percolation(1 To NumMonth + 1)
    ReDim Runoff(1 To NumMonth + 1)

   For i = 1 To NumMonth

    Month(i) = Cells(4 + i, 1).Value
    Precip(i) = Cells(4 + i, 2).Value
    RefET(i) = Cells(4 + i, 3).Value
    Next i


For j = 1 To 1
      WC(j) = Cells(3 + j, 11).Value

     Next j

     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub



Sub WaterBalanceMediterranean()

    Dim fc As Double
    fc = Cells(4, 7).Value
    NumMonth = 12
    i = 1
    j = 2

    Dim pwp,dz As Double

    Do
        If WC(j) >= pwp And (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i)) < Precip(i) Then
            Runoff(i) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i))) * 0.5
            Percolation(i) = (Precip(i) - (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i))) * 0.5
            WC(j) = fc
            WCinit(j) = WC(j - 1)    
        ElseIf WC(j) >= pwp And (fc - WC(j - 1) + RefET(i)) > Precip(i) Then
            Runoff(i) = 0
            Percolation(i) = 0
            WC(j) = WC(j - 1) + Precip(i) - RefET(i)
            WCinit(j) = WC(j - 1)
        Else
            Runoff(i) = 0
            Percolation(i) = 0
            WC(j) = pwp
            WCinit(j) = WC(j - 1)
        End If
        j = j + 1
        i = i + 1
    Loop While j < 14


End Sub
```

Comment: There's a lot of code there. A lot of it seems irrelevant to the problem. I suspect if you try to cut the code down as much as you can (while still recreating the problem) you'll end up solving this yourself. However, my first guess is that you're setting j to be equal to 2 before the loop, and you don't want to do this (do you?). Try entering `j=0` or whatever value you want before `Do`

Comment: A lot of your code is also pretty redundant. `For i = 1 To 1`. `j=1: j=2`.

Comment: I was trying to set j=1 to set the initial value, than start the loop at j=2.

Comment: is pwp always supposed to be 0?

Comment: Oh, I see you removed that in your edit. I take it the value of pwp isn't relevant. When you step through the code, is the execution flow strange?

Comment: no, pwp=0.1. I read in that cell value from a speadsheet

Comment: All the values read in correctly, it does the first step correctly. However, the first WC(j) value meets the first condition of the loop. It doesnt seem to be setting the next WC(j) value in the array (it says empty). If I walk through the code it will say WC(j): empty=fc:0.3. Therefore it will skip to the last condition of the loop (else) for the remainder of the loop. I am not sure why it keeps saying the next WC(j) is empty and not assigning values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you are using the variable `pwp` before assigning it a value. In VBA, defining multiple variables separated by commas will not give them both a type. For example, define pwp and dz like this: `Dim pwp, dz as Double`, and then view them like this:

```
MsgBox "pwp = " & pwp & " , dz = " & dz
```

You will get this: `pwp =  , dz = 0`

In the case of your code, the pwp is being called in the "If" block before it has been assigned a value. If you ever reach this block, your code will be broken thereafter. Changing the variable definition to `Dim pwp as Double, dz as Double` should fix this problem.

---

Furthermore, the real answer to this question is that you are doing a lot of things wrong here. The cause of this specific issue could be any number of things that we cannot identify, especially since we have no clue what data is in each referenced cell. My suggestion would be to do the following and get back to us:

1. Consolidate the code into one subroutine.
2. Use For...Next loops instead of Do While loops combined with an
   incremental variable.
3. Remove absolutely pointless code such as

   ```
   For j = 1 To 1
         WC(j) = Cells(3 + j, 11).Value

        Next j
   ```

   This snippet should be `WC(1) = Cells(14,11).Value` . . . Much simpler.

Plus maybe a few other changes that I would make but can't say from experience will cause any issues should you do it your way. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your arrays as arrays of double:

```
Dim WC() As Double
Redim WC(1 to NumMonth + 1) As Double 'Type is not necessary here, but no harm AFAIK
```

Because they're declared as arrays of variants they're not assigned a value to begin with. If you're doing something reasonably computationally expensive this change will speed up your computation as well.

An alternative, if you really don't want to use doubles, is to zero your array before using it.

I apologise for asking you to remove as much code as you could from your question, given that I had to go back and see what you'd edited out, but there was a lot of code there and a lot of it was unnecessary to reproduce the problem. Not to mention you removed it somewhat indiscriminately. I hope you don't take this criticism on the chin; hopefully just the fact that I've followed through and answered your question demonstrates that I'm being earnest. Anyway, hope this solves your problem :).

Comment: This doesnt help the problem. I am still having the same issue. The WC(j) adn WCinit(j) arrays are staying empty and not generating values from the array

Comment: Right. Bummer. OK, when you first run through the `WaterBalanceMediterranean` routine, `j = 2`, right? But you haven't actually put anything in `WC(j)` (specifically, `WC(2)`), right?. So in your first conditional `WC(j) >= pwp` you will always be comparing an empty array element with pwp. Is this intentional? Correct me if I'm wrong.